# How can I use the set of linear models to obtain a single equation?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, linear

This is my new attempt to rewrite the previous question about combining a few linear regression models into single equation. The background is that I have a set of dependent variables Y which is identical (say 1,2,3,4,5) for every one of the observations. In every observation I’ve measured more than 100 different datasets of independent variables X.
Due to “built-in” collinearity of X variables (and their high number) the multiple regression is failing because of "ill-conditioned matrix" error that I get in the software I use.

The simplified example of what I am trying to do:

Set_1: y={1,2,3,4,5}; x1={10,20,30,40,50}; y=a1+b1X1
Set_2: y={1,2,3,4,5}; x2={100,200,300,400,500}; y=a2+b2X2
                     ….
Set_n: y={1,2,3,4,5};  xn={ ... }; y=an+bnXn

Is that possible (as I’m thinking) to combine all the n resulting linear models so that I can come up with a single equation. Since the X variables are highly correlated so probably the desired model could look something like this:

Y = A + b1X1 + b2X2 + … + bnXn

So the actual question is how can I use the set linear models to obtain a single equation?
All the help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can't derive the combined multiple regression model from the individual separate models, since the result depends on the relationships amongst the various $x$ variables.

If you have the original data, you could fit a straight multiple regression to $y$ on $x_1, x_2, x_3, ... x_k$, (assuming you have enough data to estimate all the parameters), though if your example data is remotely typical you'll have multicollinearity problems.